# Add Menu Item not displaying for all Admins

Tags: wordpress, menu

We are using civi 5.3 on Wordpress 4.9

recently we created some custom menus items to go on the top navigation menu They are the parent tab.   Some Administrators report that they can see them, while others report that they cannot see them.   I checked, and all of us are in the same groups and have the same permissions.
I tested it in Google Chrome and saw the new menu items. 
I tested it in Explorer and saw the new menu items
Then I tested on on my ipad with Safari with the same admin account as the other two tests and I do NOT see the new menu items, even after clearing Civi's cache and my Ipads cache.  This does not make sense to me.  Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.   Civi's top menu is not responsive.  If you have a high screen resolution, menu items on the right side will disappear.  Try for experimental reasons, log into civi, hold down your Ctrl key and press the + key a few times and watch as menu tabs on the right side disappear.